# Multiple row in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, grouping

I am stuck with a messy structure and require help in writing a query, this is my current query

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  `name` , trnid,  `material` , SUM( quantity )qty , SUM( price ) price, SUM( preturn ) return 
FROM  `transactions` a
JOIN item_master b ON a.material = b.id
GROUP BY material, trnid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Output:**

[image: sql output]

If you see above there are 2 record for same material (trnd 1 is purchase qty & trnd 2 is issue qty) I want these to be a single record with the following columns.

```
name | material | purqty | issqty
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT  name, material,
        SUM(case when trnid = 1 then quantity else 0 end) as purchaseqty,
        SUM(case when trnid = 2 then quantity else 0 end) as issueqty
FROM transactions t JOIN
     item_master im
     ON t.material = im.id
GROUP BY name, material
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Comment: Perfect and accepted only thing was i just needed to group by material and remove name to get the right result according to my structure. thanks :)